# Embedding discrete functions as continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, number-theory, set-theory

$\require{AMScd}$
Given a map $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. Is there a countable set $A \subset [0,1]$, bijection $\tau:\mathbb{N} \to A$, and a continuous function $g \in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, such that $\tau \circ f = g \circ \tau$, i.e.,
$$
f(n) =  \tau^{-1}(g(\tau(n)), \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

$$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{N} @>{f}>> \mathbb{N} \\
@V{\tau}VV @A{\tau^{-1}}AA \\
A @>{g}>> A 
\end{CD}
$$

Try for example:
$$
f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1, ~ n=2k+1\\
n/2, ~n=2k
\end{cases}, k \in \mathbb{N},
$$
and another example:
$f(n) = m$ if $n$ is a product of $m$ prime numbers (identical or different).